# Moving rows into another sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

In row 1 I have headers and then my data starts in row 2. In column K, I have job IDs. These are constantly changing, and the range of K is always changing as well. What I am trying to do is run a macro so that anything with the same number multiple times is moved to another sheet, along with the header row.

For example, lets say K2 is 10, K3 is 14, K4 is 10, and K5 is 13. I would basically want 4 worksheets, 1 with both of the rows of data that contains the 10's, 1 with 14 and 1 with 13. While also copying the header row over too

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is very possible with a loop.

Comment: Can you please help me make a code? I know nothing about VBA and tend to just piece things together online to see if they work

Comment: "I know nothing about VBA". That's fine, but then don't try writing code you don't understand. Do it with formulae, which are a lot easier to understand and for you to maintain. I assume "always changing" means daily/weekly/monthly, rather than in real time? Have one sheet which is Data (input) and one or more which are output. I use Pivot Tables; some people prefer SUMIF. If Pivot Tables, do you really need three separate output sheets, or would it work to have the output grouped by job ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example:

range from column A to K with header at row 1

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, LastRowFiltered As Long
    Dim sourceRange As Range, filteredRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range, dict As Object, value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your source sheet name
    
    ' Define the source range
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Set sourceRange = wsSource.Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
    
    'add unique values to dictionary
    For Each cell In sourceRange
        If Not dict.Exists(CStr(cell)) Then
            dict(CStr(cell)) = True
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'loop thru each value in the dictionary
    For Each value In dict.Keys
        'filter based on dictionary value
        wsSource.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=value
        LastRowFiltered = wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'set filtered range to copy only the visible rows
        Set filteredRange = wsSource.Range("A1:K" & LastRowFiltered).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         ' Create a new worksheet for the filtered data
        Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=wsSource)
        'copy filtered range to new worksheet
        filteredRange.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A1")
        'rename sheet  to value
        wsDestination.Name = value
    Next value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```